# Excel VBA open same workbook twice, but one instance is read-only

Tags: excel, vba

I created a read-only shortcut to a workbook that is writeable. Doing this, I can simultaneously open separate read-only and writeable instances of the same workbook when I manually click the shortcut and the actual document separately. However I can't seem to duplicate this in VBA code. Trying to open the same workbook from the read-only instance using VBA code closes the read-only instance and leaves me with only the writeable one, EG

```
Workbook.Open filename:=ActiveWorkbook.FullName, editable:=True
```

Running this from the read-only instance terminates the instance and replaces it with a writeable one. I'd like to be able to have both, but no idea how to do this? Reason is I want to be able to publish changes made in read-only instance to writeable one with user only needing write access to the writeable instance for a few seconds, enough time for the VBA code to open it, publish the changes, and quickly save and exit and re-activate read-only instance. This allows multiple people in a team to almost concurrently make changes to the same workbook without having to suffer the limitations of 'Share Workbook', while also simultaneously being able to view the document.

But what if someone makes changes in between? Well, the user is told to reload the read-only instance if any changes have been made by someone else since the user opened the document, which just calls the above code where editable = false.

Help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method will open the workbork in the current instance and therefore as you say will replace the current open workbork.  You need to create a new excel application reference and open it using that e.g:

```
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
Dim xlWrkBk As Excel.WorkBook

xlApp.WorkBooks.Open FILENAME, , READ ONLY (True/False)

Set xlWrkBk = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook

xlApp.Visible = True
```

Hopefully that should take you in the right direction : )

Comment: I still seem to be having an add-in problem. Tools->Add-Ins shows them as installed for the writeable instance, but the code does not get loaded. Calling add-in code from the writeable instance does not work. I am stumped again :-\

Comment: Is this an additional add-in that you are using in Excel, or are you referring to some VBA code in the open document?

Comment: I didn't solve the specific problem at hand, but I think I may have a better solution. I haven't fully tested it but it uses ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess method, basically change access to writeable, saving the changes, then changing it back to read-only. Of course, the document is checked first to see if any changes have been made since the document was opened for read-only, and if so it asks the user to refresh the document before doing this.

Comment: @Wes To be honest, having multiple people working on the same spreadsheet with a mix of read or write mode based on the updates they make is a bad model. If it is possible to transfer to a database approach instead then this should cause far less headache's.

Comment: I am not sure if the database approach is applicable to what I need, correct me if I'm wrong. I am not dealing with data in cells and calculations, but shapes (text boxes, pictures, groups, etc). Basically, it is an electronic kanban board completely tailored for our needs. The shapes represent virtual post-its. We like Excel because of the grids, the customize-ability through VBA, its ability to generate metrics, etc. But if a better solution can be accomplished through a database, I'm all ears.

Comment: @Wes Ah I see, your absolutely right a database is not suitable for this type of work, unfortunately however, Excel does not really lend itself to a multi user interface. A quick google search reveals some free Kanban software (I'm sure your already aware of) if any of these support simultaneous updates then this is likely better than using Excel.

Comment: Yea our company unfortunately is really paranoid when it comes to open source software, I mean extremely paranoid. I doubt they will let me borrow any existing kanban software.

Answer (score 0):

Open the workbook Editable, then SaveCopyAs to a temp folder with a temp filename (must be different filename), then open the copy Read-Only